# masterpage after migration from sp2010 to sp2013, topbar has strange backgroundcolor!

Tags: master-page

My colleage has migrated sp2010 to sp2013. He backuped the content db and restored it on another farm in sp 2013. Now the sharepoint portal is running, but the topbar is showing some ugly background color. I changed the theme and masterpage, but still see the ugly background color.

how can I change it or use the original sharepoint masterpage and theme (blue office)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did your colleague made any customizations to the farm? Use F12 developer tool to determine what element is causing the color.

[Branding issues that may occur when upgrading to SharePoint 2013](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/branding-issues-that-may-occur-when-upgrading-to-sharepoint-2013-HA104052656.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. There was a custom css enabled in the masterpage setetings in site settings.